# CSS - table cell - min-width - percentage and pixels: How to solve this?

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are some similar questions however  I did not find any satisfying answer so far. I have a responsive table like in the examples (WordPress admin actually).

The HTML can only be changed to a certain degree - I have to use tables. I want a cell to have a minimum width in pixels and a minimum width in percent.

Like this:

```
.input-cell {
    min-width:40%;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

Only the second property will take action therefore this does not help. To make things even worse `min-width` does not work with table cells no matter weather I use `table-layout:fixed` or `table-layout:auto;`.

The following example demonstrates the table with a normal `width` style.

```css
table {
   width:100%;
   table-layout:auto;
}

.input-cell {
   width:40%;
}

textarea, input {
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Setting</th>
        <th scope="row">Value</th>
        <th scope="row">Beschreibung</th>
        <th scope="row">ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
  <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
  <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
    <textarea id="foo" name="bar" rows="7">Lorem ipsum ...</textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
  <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
  <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
    <input type="text" name="lorem" id="aliquot" value="abc" />
  </td>
  <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any CSS way how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Which of the 2 `min-width` has precedence?

Comment: Also, when you say `min-width: 40%`, 40% of what?

Comment: @LGSon With min-width:40% I mean 40% of the full table width. Both min-width should take action. The min-width pixels problem can be solved with a span with min-width around the input elements. Problem is that min-width does not work on table cells so I still do not have a solution for the min-width percentage.

Comment: Is the table always full browser width?

Comment: You may comment at my posted answer regarding whether the table is always full browser width or not, and if not, how?

Comment: The [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) and [2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths) specifications state that: the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `div` as an immediate child of the `input-cell` and give that `min-width: 40vw` (do note I'm using `40vw` viewport width units), and then either add another element between the `div` and the `textarea`, or simply as I did here, give the `textarea` a `min-width: 200px`, both your *minimum width's* requirements are fulfilled.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/771fr6fc/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.input-cell {
  width: 40%;
}

.input-cell > div {
  min-width: 40vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

textarea,
input {
  width: 95%;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr valign="top">
      <th scope="row">Setting</th>
      <th scope="row">Value</th>
      <th scope="row">Beschreibung</th>
      <th scope="row">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
      <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
        <div>
          <textarea id="foo" name="bar" rows="7">Lorem ipsum ...</textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
      <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
        <input type="text" name="lorem" id="aliquot" value="abc" />
      </td>
      <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second value is overwriting the first one, so that won't work. Just use this:

```
.input-cell {
    width:40%;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

If the 40% are more than 200px, the width will be 40%, if not, the width will be 200px.

```css
table {
   width:100%;
   table-layout:auto;
}

.input-cell {
   width:40%;
   min-width: 200px;
}

textarea, input {
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Setting</th>
        <th scope="row">Value</th>
        <th scope="row">Beschreibung</th>
        <th scope="row">ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
  <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
  <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
    <textarea id="foo" name="bar" rows="7">Lorem ipsum ...</textarea>
  </td>
  <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
  <td valign="top">Post Widget: Output callbacks</td>
  <td valign="top" class="input-cell">
    <input type="text" name="lorem" id="aliquot" value="abc" />
  </td>
  <td class="description" valign="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  <td class="cis_field_id" valign="top">master_cum_esse_sunc_veniat</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is that min-width does not work on table cells. The min-width in pixels can be solved by putting a span around the input elements. However width 40% is not exactly what I want as the cells should expand to a width more than 40% if enough space is available.

Answer (score 0):

In you use two properties with same name second one will take higher precedence. try tom use `table-layout:fixed;` and set `width` to `td` tag

Comment: Yeah but that does not solve the whole problem aight?

Comment: Yes. So the questions is what could I do to achieve a min-width behaviour anyway.

Comment: Try using `div` and their styles with `display:table;` and `display:table-cell` properties.

Comment: @Blackbam Check here https://jsfiddle.net/u3ybd1t1/   . I assign `min-width:200px;` to  `.td1` class

Comment: @Blackbam If not getting let me know